# CURL PHP - missing output and unknown error

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the code below to query an api however I'm not seeing any output. The header is returned however I also get an error - "An error has occurred:" with nothing else - not very helpful to say the least. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? (NB I've had to remove the user details for obvious reasons)

```
//Required Call Information;
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$remote_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xx.json';


// init the resource
$ch = curl_init();

//Header Information;
$headr = array();
$headr[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password");
$headr[] =  "X-Page:" . $pages;

// set curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$remote_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

// execute
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// echo
echo $output;

// echo
print $output;

// free
curl_close($ch);

// check status of server being called vis crul
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

//if error
if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
    // if curl_exec() returned false and thus failed
    echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
    echo 'everything was successful';
}
```

Comment: Is the error you are getting a PHP fatal error or exception?

Comment: You need to set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` opt for `curl_exec()` to return the result.

Comment: Also, when doing `if ( ! curl_exec(...) )`,  you're doing **another** call to the URL. Better use `if ( $output === FALSE )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the RETURN_TRANSFER curl opt will return data rather than a boolean when `$output = curl_exec($ch);` is called.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, fyi it turns out i also needed to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); to allow CURL to follow the redirect and retrieve information.

Comment: I am still getting `An error has occurred` though i have added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); `

Comment: faisal1208 - maybe try setting `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);` which may help with any errors. Also, check the HTTP response code as you might be getting a 404 or another error.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the following curl opt and see what you get back:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Comment: Hey J_D, thanks for the input, I've just tried this and unfortunately this doesn't change anything, I still get an error without an error message.